# How to generate pdf documents page-by-page in background tasks on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, reportlab

I need to generate a 100+ pages PDF documents. The process take a lot of data to process, and  all-at-once generation takes more time and memory that I can give.

I have tried a few different methods to hack my way though:

- [xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/) with HTML generation and conversion
- [rportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/) to generate some pages and
- [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) for merging

With varying result I got it working, but it is slow and takes more memory than it should (sometimes hitting instance soft memory limit). Currently I generate some sections in different tasks storing each in blobstore and merge those with pyPdf, but it chokes on larger documents.

The document I'm generating is not that complicated, mostly tables and text, no internal references, no TOC, no anything that should be aware of the rest of the document. I can live with platypus for layouting and I do not need no fancy document look or HTML2PDF conversion.

The goal is to generate the document as fast as datastore will allow it. Parallel page generation would be nice but is not required.

I was thinking of page-by-page generation with [blobstore files api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview?hl=pl-PL#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore), where each task would generate a single page and last task would finalize blobstore file making it readable. But I cant seem to find on how to, pause generation, store partial PDF to stream, and them resume generation with that stream to generate next page in a different task.

So my question is:

**How on GAE generate a larger than a few pages PDF document, splitting the generation between task requests, then store the resulting document in the blobstore?**

If generation splitting is not possible with reportlab, then how to minimize the footprint of merging different PDF documents so it would fit the limits set by GAE task request?

**UPDATE:**
Alternatives to Conversion API much appreciated.

**2nd UPDATE**
Conversion API is being decommissioned, so that's not an option now.

**3rd UPDATE**
Can Pileline or MapReduce API's help here?

Comment: Do you have a way of splitting the source data into page-sized chunks without doing the actual conversion? If so, you could write a function that uses replortlab to generate single pages and use `multiprocessing.Pool.map` to run that in parallel over a list of chunks of all your input. As the last step use pyPdf to merge the pages into a single document.

Comment: I already do something similar without much success, the merging takes to much time to finish during task (must be less than 10 min) for some documents. Maybe I do it the wrong way, anyway I would like a code example on how to do it properly.

Comment: Fast typesetting of big documents sounds like a job for TeX (possibly with the LaTeX or conTeXt macro packages). You'd have to run that on a separate server though.

Comment: Thank's but no thank's. If using background tasks is out of the question then I could use GAE backend instance, and with little or no effort my reportlab based code would work. But these documents are not that big, and PDF is really a stream of commands, IMO it should be possible to pause-resume operation based on tasks and blobstore file stream as storage.

Comment: Are you using Platypus with ReportLab?  Platypus uses a lot of memory out of necessity because it builds the document out of lots of objects.  ReportLab uses exponentially less memory if you don't use Platypus (but at the cost of simplicity).

Comment: I do but only on individual pages, and there where no problems with their generation, but I have problems with merging by pyPdf. That's why I was thinking about streamlining generation page-by-page, the way that each task would generate 1 page, pause, store the partial PDF to the blobstore then queue new task for the next page, where there the generation would resume.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the new Conversion API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/overview

Comment: There is a 60s limit on, How big documents have you generated with that? I think the person before me tried that and failed to get good results. This API is pretty basic: how do you insert page breaks for example?

Comment: If you run it on a Task Queue then it's 10min limit: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred

Comment: Are you telling that [maximum deadline 60s put on conversion request](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/overview#Limits) is waived off if conversion API is used from a task?

Comment: @WooYek What makes you think your conversion request will take more than 60 seconds?

Comment: The "Beware the 60s time limit" footnote ;) But, anyway I'll try it. I'm maintaining someone else's code and was hoping that the overhaul — and throwing all the reportlab based code — would not be needed :/

Comment: Conversion API is being decommissioned.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest installing wkhtmltopdf on app engine. Wkhtmltopdf is a command line tool to render html into pdf.

Create the html files and then convert them to pdf one by one using wkhtmltopdf.

On windows you can use (under linux based systems it's something similar):

```
def create_pdf(in_html_file=None, out_pdf_file=None, quality=None):
    pathtowk = 'C:/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe {0} {1} {2}'    

    if quality == 1: # super quality no compression
        args_str = '--encoding utf-8 --disable-smart-shrinking --no-pdf-compression --page-size A4 --zoom 1 -q -T 15.24mm -L 25.4mm -B 20.32mm  -R 33.02mm'
    elif quality == 2: # moderate quality some compression
        args_str = '--encoding utf-8 --disable-smart-shrinking --page-size A4 --zoom 1 -q -T 15.24mm -L 25.4mm -B 20.32mm  -R 33.02mm'
    else: # poor quality max compression
        args_str = '--encoding utf-8 --page-size A4 --zoom 1 -q -T 15.24mm -L 25.4mm -B 20.32mm  -R 33.02mm'

    os.system(pathtowk.format(args_str, in_html_file, out_pdf_file))
```

Alternatively you can use `subprocess.call(pathtowk.format(args_str, in_html_file, out_pdf_file))` to execute wkhtmltopdf (it is better to my opinion).

When conversion process get completed use PyPdf2 for merging the generated PDFs into single file.